# How to use setConstraints() for a custom constraint on BaseFieldDefinition?

Tags: entities, 9

I'm refactoring a node content type into a custom entity.

On this entity, I add a datetime field:

```
$fields['target_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
          ->setLabel(t('Target date'))
          ->setCardinality(1)
          ->setRequired(TRUE)
          ->setConstraints(['DateTimeMidnightOnly' => DateTimeMidnightOnlyValidator::class])
          ->setSetting('datetime_type', 'datetime')
          ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
          ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
            'weight' => 10,
          ])
          ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

However, when I attempt to save a new entity of this entity type, I'm getting the following error:

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: No default option is
> configured for constraint
> "Drupal\mymodule\Plugin\Validation\Constraint\DateTimeMidnightOnly". in
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 811 of
> /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

I also tried this:

```
          ->setConstraints(['DateTimeMidnightOnly'])
```

Which gives the error:

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: The "0" plugin does not
> exist. Valid plugin IDs for Drupal\Core\Validation\ConstraintManager
> are: Callback, Blank, NotBlank, Email, CKEditor5Element,
> CKEditor5ToolbarItemDependencyConstraint, StyleSensibleElement,
> CKEditor5MediaAndFilterSettingsInSync, SourceEditingRedundantTags,
> CKEditor5EnabledConfigurablePlugins,
> CKEditor5FundamentalCompatibility,
> SourceEditingPreventSelfXssConstraint, UniqueLabelInList,
> CKEditor5ToolbarItemConditionsMet, CKEditor5ToolbarItem, CommentName,
> DateTimeFormat, ValidDynamicReference, FileValidation....

I'm clearly calling `setConstraints()` wrong, because this constraint worked when I added it on my content type using `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()`:

```
function mymodule_entity_bundle_field_info_alter(array &$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type, string $bundle): void {
  $entity_type = $entity_type->id();
  if ($entity_type === 'node') {
    if (isset($fields['field_datetime_review_target'])) {
      $fields['field_datetime_review_target']->addConstraint('DateTimeMidnightOnly');
    }
  }
}
```

What's the right way to set `->setConstraints()` to add a custom constraint plugin?  Or, is this actually the wrong way and I should always use `hook_entity_bundle_field_info_alter()`?

Comment: You can use `setConstraints()` to set an entire array, but then you need to apply the correct array structure, where the options are the array values. `addConstraint()` is more user friendly and it should work in your case as well.

Comment: @4uk4 Yeah, I was using the wrong method, as you point out.  I think your comment is the answer so please repost as an answer so that I can accept.

Comment: If you still wanted to use setConstraint() here is a working example https://git.drupalcode.org/sandbox/Bhanu951-3103712/-/blob/8.x-dev/omdb_api/src/Entity/OmdbApiEntity.php#L793